# Съезжают названия столбцов в столбчатой диаграмме

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Рисую столбцы по данным. Каждому столбцу должна соответствовать подпись (название), но они, почему-то, "съезжают". Не могу понять, как это исправить.

```html
+---------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|        Сфера        |   1   |   2   |   3   |   4   |
+---------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Сфера полностью     | 27,64 | 24,8  | 23,38 | 16,67 |
| Общественные        | 24,28 | 26,1  | 20,29 | 20,67 |
| Потребительские     | 30,65 | 26,69 | 21,91 | 15,28 |
| Производственные    | 28,03 | 25,46 | 22,4  | 16,48 |
| Профессиональные    | 27,39 | 24,81 | 23,04 | 16,09 |
| Распределительные   | 28,44 | 24,63 | 23,36 | 16,74 |
| Медицина            | 28,01 | 26,25 | 22,52 | 17,07 |
| Образование         | 26,75 | 24,62 | 25,8  | 20,42 |
| Соц_обеспечение     | 28,75 | 22,13 | 29,84 | 23,41 |
| Гостиницы           | 29,7  | 26,21 | 21,81 | 15,23 |
| Рестораны           | 33,17 | 27,96 | 22,15 | 15,4  |
| Лизинг              | 28,03 | 25,46 | 22,4  | 16,48 |
| Бизнес_консалтинг   | 28,24 | 24,93 | 22,75 | 18,92 |
| Маркетинг           | 29,09 | 27,19 | 20,28 | 15,3  |
| Недвижимость        | 30    | 25,91 | 20,81 | 14,14 |
| Страхование         | 27,26 | 24,78 | 23,11 | 15,86 |
| Юристы              | 27,41 | 24,01 | 22,71 | 18,25 |
| Курьеры             | 29,02 | 26,44 | 22,49 | 15,46 |
| Логисты             | 28,16 | 24,43 | 23,45 | 16,7  |
| Телеком             | 28,54 | 22,79 | 24,11 | 17    |
| Транспорт_перевозки | 29,82 | 25,61 | 22,97 | 17,7  |
+---------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import workbook #pip install openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_excel('Сфера.xlsx', sheet_name='Свод2')
df_harakteristika1 = pd.read_excel('Сфера.xlsx', sheet_name='Свод2', usecols=df.iloc[:, 1:3])

def opisatelnie(color, df1, name_of_histogram, path):
    for col in df1.columns:
        plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7)) 
        patches = plt.bar(df['Сфера'], df1[col], edgecolor='black')
        plt.title(name_of_histogram.format(str(col)))
        plt.xticks(df['Сфера'], rotation=45)
        plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2, top=0.70)
        jet = plt.get_cmap(color, len(patches))
        for i in range(len(patches)):
            patches[i].set_facecolor(jet(i))
        plt.draw()
        plt.savefig(path.format(
                str(col)))
        plt.close()

opisatelnie('BuPu', df_harakteristika1, "Характеристика, {}, Сфера.png", "C:/Users/Я/source")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А они кажется не съезжают, у них просто центр надписи под риской столбца, а не правый крайний край, как вы может ожидали.

Comment: Да и зачем весь этот огород? Используйте seaborn, который вы подключили, он сам неплохо всё должен изобразить, без низкоуровневой рутины этой. Если только вам для учебного задания надо.

Comment: Если хотите так много столбцов сделайте горизонтальные бары с надписями слева да и всё. Через тот же `seaborn` будет вполне красиво выглядеть: `sns.barplot`

Comment: Да, нужно сначала с этим кодом попробовать разобраться, а потом на seaborn заняться отрисовкой

Comment: В `seaborn` не придётся скорее всего так низкоуровнево всё затачивать, он многое сам красивое делает сразу 'из коробки'